# FIR filter in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, filtering

at the moment i'm trying to implement a FIR lowpass filter. The FIR coefficients are calculated in MATLAB. Now I need to implement the FIR algorithm in C++.

I defined a class as filter and a function of FIR as:

```
double * Filter::FIR (double x[])
{

    unsigned int jj;
    unsigned int pp;
    double sum;


    pp = 0;

    // input values
    memcpy(&_x_sign, &x, sizeof(x));


    for (pp = 0; pp < order+1; pp++)

    {
        sum = 0 ;
        for (jj = 0; jj <  order+1; jj++)
        {
            sum += _b[jj] * _x_sign[pp - jj];
        }

        _y_sign[pp] = sum;

    }

    return (_y_sign);
}
```

the _x_sign as an array does not works when in the loop (pp - jj)is a negative number.
How can I modify my FIR filter ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see you're trying to do a convolution and if you want to avoid a segfault by indexing outside of the array you need to change the expression.
For example you can use instead of

```
_x_sign[pp -jj]
pp>jj? _x_sign[pp - jj] : 0
```

In this case you avoid indexing outside the memory by using the ternary operator (if jj is bigger than pp the _x_sign[pp - jj] won't be evaluated)

You can also change the limits of your for with

```
for (jj = 0; jj < order+1&& jj< pp+1; jj++)
    {
        sum += _b[jj] * _x_sign[pp - jj];
    }
```

Second solution is better because you avoid making a bigger loop when it's useless.